# Card deck for Blackjack in an OOP style

Tags: c++, object-oriented, game, playing-cards

So far I have made a class called Deck, to create and shuffle a deck of cards, and a class called Player, which I want to use to create the gambler and the dealer.

My Player class inherits from the Deck class, so the players can access the created deck. My problem is that because I create 2 objects from Player class (gambler and dealer), this means 2 decks of cards are also created. Of course it should be that both players are using the same deck, how can I achieve this?

```
class Deck {
public:
    int MinDeckSize = 10;
    std::vector<int> DeckOfCards;
    
    // Deck of cards values - with aces worth 11
    void DeckInit() {
    // All the values in a deck of cards
        DeckOfCards = { 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11,
            2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11,
            2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11,
            2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11 };
        
    // Fisher-Yates algorithm to shuffle the deck
        for (int i = 51; i > 0; i--) {
          int r = rand()%(i + 1);
          std::swap(DeckOfCards[i], DeckOfCards[r]);
        }
    }
    
    // Pick a card from the deck, and remove the card from DeckOfCards
    int DrawCard() {
        int Card = DeckOfCards[0];
        DeckOfCards.erase(DeckOfCards.begin());
        return Card;
    }
    
    // Check the Deck has enough cards to play BlackJack
    bool IsDeckBigEnough() {
        return DeckOfCards.size() >= MinDeckSize;
    }
    
};
```

Comment: It's wrong to inherit Player from Deck. Inheritance means you can do with children everything you can do with a parent, e.g. if you can shuffle a Deck, then you also should be able to "shuffle a player". This, of course, is wrong. Probably you need a Game object with (at least) two players and a deck.

Comment: Rule of thumb: inheritance means "is a" relation. If you inherit Car class from Transport class, then a car is a transport.

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The dealer is not actually a player, or at least not completely a player. An Ace can be either 1 or 11 and it depends on the cards in the hand, your implementation doesn't support this. While it doesn't really matter in Black Jack, the cards should have suits associated with them so start with 1 and number up to 52. A player can ask for a card or not ask for a card, the dealer is always the one to draw the card.

Comment: I can't actually write an answer because the question is off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a nice Deck class that you've made, but allow me to suggest a few changes:

- Make `MinDeckSize` and `DeckOfCards` private, for encapsulation.
- Often the code style is such that types such as classes are in `PascalCase`, - and variables are either in `camelCase` or `snake_case`.
- Use a constructor to initialize the class, instead of the `DeckInit` function.
- Make a distinct function for shuffling, and make it use the vector size instead of a fixed size.
- Rename `IsDeckBigEnough` to `IsBigEnoughForBlackJack`

```
class Deck {
    // Those are now privates
    int minDeckSize = 10;
    std::vector<int> deckOfCards;

public:
    // Constructor, avoid having to call an Init function
    // Deck of cards values - with aces worth 11
    Deck()
    {
        // All the values in a deck of cards
        deckOfCards = {
            2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
            2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
            2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
            2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11};

        FisherYatesShuffle();
    }

    void FisherYatesShuffle()
    {
        //Use the current vector size instead of the previously hardcoded 51
        //Prefer --i over i--
        for(int i = deckOfCards.size() - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            int r = rand() % (i + 1);
            std::swap(deckOfCards[i], deckOfCards[r]);
        }
    }

    // Pick a card from the deck, and remove the card from DeckOfCards
    int DrawCard()
    {
        int Card = deckOfCards[0];
        deckOfCards.erase(deckOfCards.begin());
        return Card;
    }

    // Check the Deck has enough cards to play BlackJack
    bool IsDeckBigEnough()
    {
        return deckOfCards.size() >= minDeckSize;
    }
};
```

The Player class could have been included the question to make it easier to answer.

Regardless, it seems that the needed relationship between Deck and Player is:
A Player *has a* Deck, and not
A Player *is a* Deck

Since you would like both players to have a deck, let's use a common IDeck interface.

The classes could then look like this:

```
//Interface class, with every functions pure virtual
class IDeck {
public:
    virtual void FisherYatesShuffle() = 0;
    virtual int DrawCard() = 0;
    virtual bool IsDeckBigEnough() = 0;
};

class Deck : public IDeck {
    // Those are now privates
    int minDeckSize = 10;
    std::vector<int> deckOfCards;

public:
    // Constructor, avoid having to call an Init function
    // Deck of cards values - with aces worth 11
    Deck()
    {
        // All the values in a deck of cards
        deckOfCards = {
            2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
            2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
            2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
            2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11};

        FisherYatesShuffle();
    }

    virtual void FisherYatesShuffle() override
    {
        //Use the current vector size instead of the previously hardcoded 51
        //Prefer --i over i--
        for(auto i = deckOfCards.size() - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            int r = rand() % (i + 1);
            std::swap(deckOfCards[i], deckOfCards[r]);
        }
    }

    // Pick a card from the deck, and remove the card from DeckOfCards
    virtual int DrawCard() override
    {
        int Card = deckOfCards[0];
        deckOfCards.erase(deckOfCards.begin());
        return Card;
    }

    // Check the Deck has enough cards to play BlackJack
    virtual bool IsDeckBigEnough() override
    {
        return deckOfCards.size() >= minDeckSize;
    }
};

class Player : public IDeck {
    std::shared_ptr<Deck> deck;

public:
    Player(std::shared_ptr<Deck> deck) :
        deck{deck}
    {
    }

    // Implement IDeck
    virtual void FisherYatesShuffle() override
    {
        deck->FisherYatesShuffle();
    }

    // Implement IDeck
    virtual int DrawCard() override
    {
        return deck->DrawCard();
    }

    // Implement IDeck
    virtual bool IsDeckBigEnough() override
    {
        return deck->IsDeckBigEnough();
    }

    //Other player functions
};

void Demo()
{
    //Initialized and shuffled automatically from the Deck constructor
    auto oneDeck = std::make_shared<Deck>();

    //Two players share the same deck
    //Could be a vector<Player> instead
    Player firstPlayer(oneDeck);
    Player secondPlayer(oneDeck);

    //Example usage
    if(firstPlayer.IsDeckBigEnough())
        firstPlayer.DrawCard();
}
```

All players will share the same deck.
All player's Deck can be accessed using the IDeck interface.

Hopefully this is helpful.
Always keep learning :) !

Comment: You are still deriving `Player` from `Deck` which is nonsensical: `class Player : public IDeck`. The idea of creating an interface is very C#-ish. A better solution would have been to make the necessary items `public` in `Deck` so that it is accessible to `Player`. You could also have used a reference to the deck instead of a shared pointer.

Comment: #-ish indeed, but the necessary items are already public in Deck, and already accessible to Player. Did you mean something else? In this case the Deck is created in the same scope as the two players, so making it a reference would work in that scenario. But making a reference also assume that the Deck will not go out of scope and be destroyed before any players using it does. This is why it is a shared_ptr.

Comment: I would rather do something like this: [TIO](https://bit.ly/3bWEN5D)

Comment: You will have to do some really screwed up stuff to allow `Deck` to get out of scope before `Player` but I guess it's possible [TIO](https://tio.run/##hVBNTwMhEL3vr5j0UnDTtJp42V176sWb8WxiCLCWyEIDg6aa/e0rsI2isekc5vO9xwz8cFi9cD5Nb1YJ2MnBElp9VhBtvb43ChXT6kMKYEaA34e@16kIaAeGijOtj9A7OwDuZaTzV@DWeHSBo3VZxrtIJagGSTaUtrn3oNlRuivolfM4F78HXkYZUU7mnZLlV0R07Xer0IE7MPL9JEQSjP7gStmzwDH73jogHkXT@Hj/M4KKhE0bQwc3tzHWNf2zWEZzGxC6DhaPNsQvW6ScKKjhmqZ0@WSW7RlGcUUzE4vOapsiuShSnnhSKVv/y4zVOE1f),  I get your point :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Start variables and member functions with lower case

It's quite common in C++ to start type names with an upper case letter, and variable and function names with a lower case letter. This makes it easy to distinguish between the two.

## Organizing your classes

> My Player class inherits from the Deck class

As mentioned by others in the comments, this is wrong. You should use inheritance primarily for "is-a" relationships. A player is not a deck, so it shouldn't inherit from a deck. A player can *have* a deck, in which case you would use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class Player {
    Deck hand;
    ...
};
```

Note that you are already using composition for `Deck` itself: a `Deck` is not a card, so you wouldn't inherit from a card. Instead, you have correctly created a member variable that holds the cards in the decks.

However, instead of using `std::vector<int>` for this, consider creating a `class Card` that represents a card, and then write:

```
std::vector<Card> cards;
```

Finally, in real life a deck of cards doesn't know anything about the game it is being used in. So having a member function that checks if the deck is big enough for Blackjack is wrong. Keep the contents of a `Deck` restricted to the cards it holds and any operations you can do on a deck, like shuffling cards, drawing cards and placing cards back on a deck.

## Hands versus decks

When you say "deck of cards", you typically think of a set of about 52 cards.
When you play a game, players typically get a few cards of the deck, and that is called their "hand", and then there typically are the drawing and discard piles. All those things are similar to a deck though, just that they can each have a variable amount of cards. You can use `class Deck` for all of those things.

## Add functions to move cards between decks

It might be nice to have member functions that allows cards to be moved from one hand/deck/pile to another. Consider having:

```
class Deck {
    ...
    void draw_from(Deck &other_deck) {
        Card card = other_deck.draw_card();
        add_card(card);
    }
    ...
};

class Player {
    Deck hand;
    ...
};

...

Deck draw_pile;
Deck discard_pile;
std::vector<Player> players(2);

draw_pile.init();

// Draw a card from the draw_pile into the first player's hand:
players[0].hand.draw_from(draw_pile);
```

## Make better use of the standard library

The standard library comes with a lot of useful [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm), including one that can shuffle the contents of a container for you: [`std::shuffle()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/shuffle).